# Background Focusing

Tags: infinity-focus

Besides setting the lense to Manual focus, can single point Auto focus be used to
focus 'beyond' a foreground of tree branches to infinity? Living in the mountains makes long distance focusing a challenge. Thanks! Canon t7i w/ 55m kit and 50-250mm tele. (amateur)

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about the phase-detection autofocus (the one you get through your viewfinder), then it is important to know that the actual AF-point is larger in area than the one you can see in your viewfinder. Therefore it would be best to **look for a gap that is slightly bigger than your chosen AF-point.**

**With contrast-detetction autofocus** (LiveView), **a gap that is as wide as the AF-point should be enough.**

---

Another possibility is to use lenses with a **[focus-limiter-switch](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/what-is-a-focus-limiter#7072)** - this feature is most often found on (higher-priced) tele-lenses, such as the [`100mm f/2.8 L IS USM Macro`](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-100mm-f-2.8-L-IS-USM-Macro-Lens-Review.aspx), the [`100-400mm f/4.5-5.6 L IS II USM`](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-100-400mm-f-4.5-5.6-L-IS-II-USM-Lens.aspx), the [`70-210mm f/4`](http://kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/70-210mm.htm), etc.p.p.. Lenses with that feature have a dedicated switch that can limit the focus-range; e.g. from 1m-∞ to 5m-∞. That way, the AF will ignore objects in front. However, few of these limiters are designed to ignore mid-range obstacles; they are mainly intended to allow shooting through fences at short distance.

The picture below shows the AF-limiter settings on the `100mm f/2.8 L IS USM Macro` - notice that it has three settings (`Full`, `0.5m-∞` & `0.3-0.5m`) that are designed to differentiate between macro and non-macro distances. Some/most lenses just have two settings.

[image: focus limiter switch of 100mm L IS USM Macro]
<sub>Image stolen from [GearOpen's Canon 100mm f/2.8 L IS USM Macro review](http://gearopen.com/cameras/canon-ef-100mm-f2-8l-macro-is-usm-lens-review-19451/)</sub>

Comment: Does the autofocus software take the limiter into account as far as differentiating near and far contrast points in software or does it simply act as a mechanical stop, keeping the focus from getting too near - but still allowing a near object to potentially "trick" the autofocus?

Comment: @Corey **that's a good question!** I don't have the knowledge to give a detailed insight into the technology, but my (somewhat limited) experience is that the omitted range will not be cycled through at all; it's like your lens has a new minimum focussing distance (MFD). So just as with the real MFD, if the AF-point is out of the focus-range, the camera will cycle through the whole (usable) focus range - or simply stop autofocussing, depending on your `C.Fn`s. All I can find in the lenses' manuals is `By setting a suitable focusing distance range, the actual autofocusing time will be shorter.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the point is small enough that you have a clear view to a high-contrast pattern in the distance.